# JMeter Write to file script is duplicating print

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm having a problem with the CSV generated, it duplicates or iterates the process of printing.

Code of printing to CSV:

[image]

CSV file generate with null record:

[image: this is the generated csv]

It shows to values `PASSED` and `null`,  I'm only expecting the value with `PASSED`.

Don't know where the `null` value came from, also in the Debug Sampler the message variable only contains `PASSED` , did not see any `null` .

Comment: you are using a postprocessor? can you show your test hierarchy?

Comment: under the thread group is the sampler and processor,, the processor is not under the sampler  ,, as i have assertions that is being  inputed in the MESSAGE variable. i put the processor outside the sampler to get the value of the assertions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use post processor for specific sampler, make sure it will execute only once by putting it under the Sampler, otherwise it can execute for other samplers in its hierarchy which you will not expect

If you want it to execute after assertions,  change to Beanshell/JSR223 Sampler after your Sampler so it will be executed once after all assertions.

See JMetet's [Execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

> ..Sampler
>
> Post-Processors> (unless SampleResult is null)
>
> Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)..

Comment: but in my test plan i only have 1 sampler

Comment: @user9923622 even Deubg Sampler is a sampler, show your test plan hierarchy

Comment: ohhh now i get it, thats why its duplicating because its outside,, but now if i put the beanshell inside the processor ,, it does not get the value of MESSAGE :( 
the message comes from the assertion

Comment: @user9923622 change to Beanshell/JSR223 Sampler after your Sampler so it will be executed once after assertion

Comment: yes , thanks a lot dude :) did not think of that :D:D:D